# Efficient way of handling expiry in a Recycler List

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

We have a chat application which has mandatory message expiry feature. So the expiry could be [5sec, 30sec, 2min, 30min, 1day, 1week]

So when you open a chat all the message items have message expiry and we keep track of all expiry time to remove the message when the time comes.

The methods we have tried to do this are

1. We used Alarms to set an alarm for when the message needs to expire. Android has this limit where you cannot set more than 500 alarms and so we could not get much ahead.
2. The second method we used uses handler and EventBus. So on creating the Adapter for RecyclerView we do this:

   handler = new Handler();

   handler.postDelayed(mUpdateExpiry, 1000);

where mUpdateExpiry is

```
Runnable mUpdateExpiry = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ExpiryCheckEvent());
        if (handler != null) handler.postDelayed(mUpdateExpiry, 1000);
    }
};
```

When ExpiryCheckEvent is triggered we check which messages have to expire and remove them. This is very inefficient and also hangs up the app when the number of messages increase.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main ... Process: xxxx.xxx, PID: 26740
                          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 122700 byte allocation with 72800 free bytes and 71KB until OOM
```

What is a good efficient way of implementing this feature?

Comment: Remove from message list and data store. We have 1000s of messages per chat since these could be group chats.

Comment: Yes the data is in a sqlite DB.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

"so call db queries every, lets say 1 minute" > Queries for fetching messages?

What about messages whose expiry is 5 second, 30 seconds? They will have to stay in view for 1 minute at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding a new alarm to each message is not a good way. the best way is to have a table in your database that includes message ides that need to be deleted at the specified time. you need to sort them by expire date-time and add the top item to alarm manager (that is closer to the current time). when the alarm manager called by android system (on first item expired time)you need to delete that id(message) from your table and add the next message expire time to the alarm manager.
for example, the user set the 30 minute to expire time to **message1** and 5 minutes to **message2** and 5 seconds to **message3**. you need to add message1,message2, and message3 to your expire table and sort them by the expire time.if the current time is 10:00:00 AM we will have this in the expire table:

1. **message3** (expire date=> 10:00:30)
2. **message2** (expire date=> 10:05:00)
3. **message1** (expire date=> 10:30:00)

so you should add 10:00:30 to the alarm manager and when it called on the time you should delete the message 3 and add 10:05:00 to the alarm manager.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Will have to handle the alarm if the phone reboots.